# List comprehension vs filter vs remove

Tags: python, list, data-structures, filter, list-comprehension

How are the latter two better than the former solution?

```
primes = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7)

# Classic solution
items = list(range(10))
for prime in primes:
    items.remove(prime)
items

# List comprehension
items = list(range(10))
[item for item in items if item not in primes]

# Filter
items = list(range(10))
list(filter(lambda item: item not in primes, items))
```

The three examples are something I came across in a book and it says that the first solutions takes O(n*m) time (n=len(items), m=len(primes)) whereas the latter two take O(n*1) time... Resulting in 50 comparisons for the first solution (slightly better actually - 40 comparisons) and just 10 for the latter.

I do not understand this. I don't understand how could it be time or memory efficient.

Here is the paragraph in the book that explains this:

> To remove or insert a single item from/into the list, Python needs to copy 
>       the entire list, which is especially heavy with larger lists. When executing 
>       this only once, it is of course not all that bad. But when executing a large 
>       number of deletions, a filter or list comprehension is a much faster 
>       solution because, if properly structured, it needs to copy the list only
>       once.
>       .... then the examples ...
>       The latter two are much faster for large lists of items. This is because the 
>       operations are much faster. To compare using n=len(items) and m=len(primes), 
>       the first takes O(m*n)=5*10=50 operations, whereas the latter two take 
>       O(n*1)=10*1=10 operations.

EDIT: 
The book is not wrong. `primes = set((1, 2, 3, 5, 7))` is the right declaration and not `primes = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7)`

Comment: Solve it on paper to understand. We probably cannot really make it clearer than the code already is.

Comment: All solutions are `O(n*m)`, because linear searching the primes list of length `m` `n` times.

Comment: @hop I did! For list comprehension, 0 is compared with the 5 primes, then 1 is compared with the 5 primes, then 2.... till 9 that brings me to 50 and not 10!

Comment: @Daniel That's what I thought but the book I read this in is pretty popular! It is called Mastering Python... doesn't make sense for there to be such a big mistake in the book! I will edit the question to include the paragraphs from the book in 2 mins

Comment: @Daniel Done... Please see if you can make sense of it!

Comment: @itachi I think that book tries to say that IN is an efficient operator to test existance. Latter two snippets can take advantage of IN and thus have a O(n) if primes would be a Set.

Comment: Are you sure the book does not define primes as a set? ie `primes = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7}`? The statement would only be true if so.

Comment: the book rather seems to imply that since `primes` is a short constant list, it's only contributing a factor to the O(). `remove()` on the other hand is `O(n)`, so you have a hidden nested loop. The other two solutions have only one straight loop.

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov You're right! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code in the book is exactly the same as you posted, then **the book is flat out wrong**.

The first example has time complexity `O(n*m)`, but so do the other two.

If `primes` were a `set` (or `dict`), then it would be true -- existence lookup with `in` operator in a hashmap has time complexity `O(1)`, but in a `list` or `tuple` has `O(n)`! Therefore, the total complexity of `O(n*m)`.

Let's check this with some measurements:

```
t = tuple(range(10000))
l = list(t)
s = set(t)
d = {i:1 for i in l}

In [16]: %%timeit
4738 in t
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.5 µs per loop

In [17]: %%timeit
4738 in l
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.4 µs per loop

In [18]: %%timeit
4738 in s
   ....: 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 36.9 ns per loop

In [19]: %%timeit
4738 in d
   ....: 
10000000 loops, best of 3: 38 ns per loop
```

Notice the lookup in `set` is `~37ns` (similar as in `dict`), 3 orders of magnitude faster than in `list`/`tuple`, `~45us`.

Comment: Add dict to testing, it should be fastest

Comment: It shouldn't be, since `set` is using `dict` internally, but I'll add it.

Comment: `.remove()` is ~ O(n) and that's where the `m*n` comes from

Comment: @hop, Yes, but other two are also `O(n*m)`: for each item in n items, check if it exist in a tuple of m (where a tuple lookup is `O(m)`).

Comment: @randomir: I didn't say you were wrong, just that that seems to be the intent of the examples.

Comment: AH! It indeed is a set. Sorry for missing out such a big detail. The book isn't wrong...

Comment: @itachi, cool, then it all makes sense. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem comes from the `items.remove(prime)`. The reason for this is because Python's lists are variable-length arrays, and not linked lists. they use a contiguous block of memory with references to other objects. If an element is inserted/removed from any position in the block, all the element in the block have to be moved to a new contiguous memory block (some optimizations are implement for inserting at the beginning or the end of the array). [see the documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html) 
You loop through the list `len(primes)` times, for each remove, you traverse items `len(items)` times. If the element is present, you copy the items list to a new contiguous block excluding the the matched item. there is an hidden cost of copying element to a new block.

The other two example traverse the list leaving all it current elements as is. And return a new list based on the provided filter.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but +1 for the insight! Learnt something new about python arrays :)

Comment: @QuoVadis: following your link, there is no word about inserting elements at the beginning. This is a O(n) operation.

Comment: IT depend of what optimization has been implemented around the initial homogeneous block.

Comment: @Daniel I guess he meant amortized O(1)